# How do I highlight certain points with custom ggplot package ggQC?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggQC)
set.seed(5555)
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month = 1:12,
                 egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.2))
Golden_Egg_df$egg_diameter[3] <- 2.5
```

Example data is generated above... to create the plot shown below. I want all points above or below the red lines highlighted, preferably with a circle around said point, in our example the third point.

I know I can accomplish this adding a `geom_point()` with an `ifelse` statement. I don't know how to strip out the upper *'red line value'* and *'lower red line'* values from `stat_QC()` to allow me to utilize my proposed method.

Here's hoping you know how and can provide the answer.

```
XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
               geom_point() + geom_line() + 
               stat_QC(method = "XmR")
```

[image: xmr]

Comment: You find the value of the red lines here `ggplot_build(XmR_Plot)$data[[3]]`. Column `y` or `yintercept`. Then you could use [`gghighlight`](https://yutani.rbind.io/post/2017-10-06-gghighlight/) for example.

Comment: Do I have to plot with `ggplot()`? Then rebuild the data frame with `ifelse()`, `ggplot_build(XmR_Plot)$data[[3]][1, 1]`, and `ggplot_build(XmR_Plot)$data[[3]][2, 1]`? **And finally plotting again with the highlight _geom()_? Or is there a shorter, elegant way? Either way I'm glad to discover your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR")
```

Here is one option where we use `ggplot_build` to extract the data from the red lines. You can read more about a `ggplot_build` object here: https://rud.is/books/creating-ggplot2-extensions/demystifying-ggplot2.html#the-ggplot_built-object

```
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
thres <- range(pb$data[[3]]$yintercept) # you need to inspect pb$data to find the right element
```

`thres` contains y-values of the red lines.

```
thres
#[1] 0.7319105 2.3820961
```

If you now want to highlight only the point above (or below) these values, add another point layer with a subset of the initial data

```
p + geom_point(
  data = subset(Golden_Egg_df,
                egg_diameter > max(thres) | egg_diameter < min(thres)),
  shape = 21,
  size = 4,
  col = "red"
)
```

[image]